# Is there a way to test video playback on mobile app

Tags: automated-tests, video-streaming, appium, robotframework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a hybrid mobile app (React native) automated testing project using robot framework and Appium, i'm looking for a way to test videos streaming.

Is there a way to test if the video playback in UI works as expected ?

Answer (score 1):

For the video apps , if you know that there is video playing , try to capture time left / time run for the video from time bar that is displayed in video. Comparing screenshot is not the solution but an workaround

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the UI tool to get a few screenshots spaced in time, then compare them to each other (verifying that they are different enough)

Comment: how can i compare between them automatically? can i hash them and compare ?

Comment: Yes, hash one of way but depends on quality. Another way is bash `compare` tool or similar like from python's `PIL`

Answer (score 0):

Like what @Nithin said.

1. Use video player to scrrenshot video at 10th minute.
2. Do robot test and capture screenshot at 10th minute.
3. Use screenshot comparison tool like applitools to comlare #2 vs #1.
   Both should identical.

Just my ideas, I am not sure if such comparison tool is realible to compare video screenshot or not.

Let me know the outcome.
I am also research how to automate video streaming testing.